# R - system is computationally singular - dealing with small numbers

Tags: matrix, markov-process, computational-statistics, matrix-inverse, singular-matrix

I'm working with a ~200x200 Markovian transition matrix of non-zero probabilities. Forcibly, these probabilities are, for the large part, going to be very small. I am trying to find the inverse of my matrix, but come up with the error:

Error in solve.default(diag(1, n) - T) : 
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.57094e-19

The smallest eigenvalue of the matrix in question is -1.169971e-15, which is not unbelievable within the scale of the problem, yet R claims that computationally this is too close to zero - is there a way of forcing R to find the inverse despite the very small numbers in question?

Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm new to stats :$

Clarification:
I'm using the inverse in a calculation of eigenvector sensitivities - the partial derivatives of the first element of the eigenvector of unity q w.r.t. an element of T $t_ij$ is given by $q_i(I-T)^(-1)_j$. Apologies for my poor latex. Further detail of the process involved found here http://www.jstor.org/stable/2157442?seq=12

Comment: [Don't invert that matrix](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/).

Comment: +1 to @AndyJones. What do you want to do with the inverse?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's very likely you don't actually need to invert this matrix - and you should generally avoid trying.

Comment: Added clarification on what I'm trying to achieve. If you could explain to me how to do this without inverting the matrix, it would be much appreciated.